# `knex.js` violates foreign key constraint when seeding

Tags: knex.js

Two seed files

```
const faker = require('faker')

exports.seed = (knex, Promise) => {
  // Deletes ALL existing entries
  return knex('posts')
    .truncate()
    .del()
    .then(() => {
      // Inserts seed entries
      return knex('posts').insert([
        {
          id: 1,
          title: faker.lorem.words(),
          body: '12 - 10',
          answers: '[12]',
          user_id: 1
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: faker.lorem.words(),
          body: '12 - 10 + 123',
          answers: '[12]',
          user_id: 1
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          title: faker.lorem.words(),
          body: '12 - 10 / 901',
          answers: '[12]',
          user_id: 1
        }
      ])
    })
}



exports.seed = function(knex, Promise) {
  // Deletes ALL existing entries
  return knex('users')
    .truncate()
    .del()
    .then(function() {
      // Inserts seed entries
      return knex('users').insert([
        { id: 1, email: 'george@stoplion', username: 'stoplion' },
        { id: 2, email: 'angelmcfood@gmail.com', username: 'testuser1' }
      ])
    })
}
```

`Posts` have a `user_id` foreign key referencing `User.id`.

I'd like to truncate all the data and seed before each test. But getting this error:

```
 Error while executing "/Users/me/Code/TallyCat-App/next-

tally/db/seeds/1_users.js" 
seed: delete from "users" - update or delete on table "users" violates 
foreign key constraint "posts_user_id_foreign" on table "posts"
```

Comment: I think this is related to the order the seeds are run, you should run the `users` seed first, since the `posts` have a foreign key to user_id. It would help if you post the migration files for those tables.

Answer (score 0):

Those seeds are written in a way that they both can be ran only to clean database, which has empty `users` and `posts` tables.

Here is what happens when DB is empty:

1. 1_users.js writes 2 rows to users table
2. 2_posts.js writes 3 rows with keys referring users

All good

This happens when there is data in table:

1. 1_users.js tries to empty the users table
2. 1_users.js script fails because there are keys referring to users table

You should write your seeding scripts in a way that all related data is added in single migration file which first truncates both of the tables and then re-populates both of the tables.

Splitting population data based on tables will not work